# Button Kotlin not clickckable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

the code below presents a buttonlogout in kotlin the button allows the user to log out and return to the main activity, but I don't understand why when I click on the button the logout function is not executed, below you find both xml and the kotlin.  Once the view is started, the user clicks on the button that allows you to return to the initial view, creates the intent, inserts the values into the intent and starts the new activity

[image: Debug image of code]

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val bottleFragment = BottleFragment()
    private val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private val profileInfoFragment = ProfileInfoFragment()
    private val fragmentHistory = mutableListOf<Fragment>(homeFragment)
    private var activeFragment: Fragment = homeFragment
    var ID_AUTH_FIREBASE = ""
    var ADMIN_KEY = ""
    var email = ""
    val bundle = Bundle()

    private val bottomNavigationListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                setFragment(homeFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                setFragment(profileInfoFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_bottle -> {
                setFragment(bottleFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            else -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
            }
        }
    }


        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(bottomNavigationListener)
        //startFragment(homeFragment)
        checkPermissions()
        try {
            var btnlogout = findViewById(R.id.buttonlogoutmain) as Button
        btnlogout.setOnClickListener { logout() }
        }
        catch(err: Exception){
            System.out.println("Errrore: "+err)
        }
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
        email = intent.getStringExtra("Email")
        ID_AUTH_FIREBASE = intent.getStringExtra("ID_AUTH_FIREBASE")
        ADMIN_KEY = intent.getStringExtra("ADMIN_KEY")
        val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", 0)
        var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
        editor.putString("Email", email)
        editor.putString("ID_AUTH_FIREBASE", ID_AUTH_FIREBASE)
        editor.putString("ADMIN_KEY", ADMIN_KEY)
        editor.commit()
        val datiPersona = APISupport.getDatiPersona(ID_AUTH_FIREBASE, email, ADMIN_KEY)
        textNome.setText(datiPersona[0])
        txtCognome.setText(datiPersona[1])
        txtResidenza.setText(datiPersona[2])
        txtTelefono.setText(datiPersona[3])
        txtEmail.setText(email)
        hometext.text = datiPersona[0] + " " + datiPersona[1]
        txtcfdesc.setText(datiPersona[5])
        txtnumeropolizaedit.setText(datiPersona[6])
        try {
            val url: URL = URL(APISupport.geturlLogo(ID_AUTH_FIREBASE, email, ADMIN_KEY))
            val bmp: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())
            imageLogo.setImageBitmap(bmp)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            System.out.println("Errore")
        }
        txtDataFineEdit.setText(datiPersona[8])
        txtDataInizioEdit.setText(datiPersona[7])


    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        checkPermissions()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        checkPermissions()
    }

    fun save() {
        System.out.println("Tap on save")
        var value = APISupport.savedatipersona(
            ID_AUTH_FIREBASE,
            email,
            ADMIN_KEY,
            txtCognome.text.toString(),
            textNome.text.toString(),
            txtTelefono.text.toString(),
            txtResidenza.text.toString(),
            txtDataInizioEdit.text.toString(),
            txtDataFineEdit.text.toString(),
            txtnumeropolizaedit.text.toString(),
            txtcfdesc.text.toString()
        )
    }

    fun logout() {
        val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", 0)
        var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
        editor.putString("Email", "")
        editor.putString("ID_AUTH_FIREBASE", "")
        editor.putString("ADMIN_KEY","")
        editor.commit()
        System.out.println("Tap on logout")
        val intent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun startFragment(fragment: Fragment, removeLast: Boolean = false) {

        if (fragment == homeFragment)
            startHomeBackground()
        else
            stopHomeBackground()

        if (removeLast)
            fragmentHistory.removeAt(fragmentHistory.lastIndex)
        if (fragmentHistory.last() != fragment)
            fragmentHistory.add(fragment)


        activeFragment = fragment
    }

    protected fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment?) {
        if (fragment == homeFragment)
            startHomeBackground()
        else
            stopHomeBackground()
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }


    fun startHomeBackground() {
        homeBackground.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun stopHomeBackground() {
        homeBackground.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                RequestCodes.PERMISSION_GPS
            )
            return
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH),
                RequestCodes.PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH
            )
            return
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE),
                    RequestCodes.PERMISSION_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
                )
                return
            }
        }

    }

    private fun Fragment.isMainFragment(): Boolean {
        when (this) {
            homeFragment, bottleFragment, profileInfoFragment -> {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {

        if (fragmentHistory.last().isMainFragment()) {
            finish()
            return
        }

        val lastIndex = fragmentHistory.lastIndex
        try {
            startFragment(fragmentHistory[lastIndex - 1], true)
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            finish()
        }
    }



}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context="com.app.videoperizie.activities.MainActivity">

    <!-- Home Background -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/oval"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonlogoutmain"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/iconback"
                android:clickable="true"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hometext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                android:text="Mario Rossi"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonsavemain"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/iconsave" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/logolive"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtviewBenvenuto"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Benvenuto"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtviewProfilo"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Il tuo profilo"
                    android:textColor="#54CFFD"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNome"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                    android:text="Nome:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/textNome"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Nome"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCognomeDesc"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Cognome:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtCognome"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Cognome"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtResidenzadesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Residenza:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtResidenza"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Residenza"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTelefonoDesc"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Telefono:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtTelefono"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Telefono"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtemaildesc"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Email:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtcfdesc"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:hint="Codice Fiscale"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtcodicefiscale"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Codice Fiscale:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtnumeropoliza"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Numero Poliza:"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtnumeropolizaedit"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Numero Poliza"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDataInizioView"
                    android:layout_width="370dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Data Inizio                                                 Data Fine"
                    android:textColor="#BABABA"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtDataInizioEdit"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Data Inizio"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtDataFineEdit"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_grey"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Data Fine"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#313E5F"
                    android:textColorHint="#313E5F"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="#FFFAFA"
        app:itemIconSize="28dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

    <!-- Fragments Container -->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did u try initialize the button and click?

Comment: @Brendon i have already tried but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't see the initialize part of buttonlogoutmain button in your code

Comment: now.............

Comment: Have u registered your SplashActivity in manifest?

Comment: the same functionality is also used in multiple views

Comment: Are you getting "Tap on logout" log?

Comment: yes tap not works...

Comment: Did you **debug** the `btnlogout.setOnClickListener` ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i have add and image of debug

Comment: try removing clickable true line from ur LogoutButton in xml and see if it works ?

Comment: @M.BilalAsif i try to remove clickable but not change anything

Comment: @riki OK it means that the clicklistener is called and then what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following part of the code

```kotlin
private lateinit var btnlogout: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        .....
    try {
        btnlogout = findViewById(R.id.buttonlogoutmain)
        btnlogout.setOnClickListener { logout() }
    } catch (err: Exception) {
        System.out.println("Errrore: " + err)
    }
        .....
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but the button doesn't work and nothing is printed in the catch

Comment: Can you print a sentence at the beginning of the logout() function to determine whether it is executed in logout()?

Comment: tried to print something but the function fails? the thing is very strange

Comment: In other words, no log is printed in the logout() function, right?

That means there is no execution to logout().

Maybe your click event was consumed by other Views.

Comment: but which? how do i figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try implement View.OnClickListener in your Activity and

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    v?.let {
        when (it.id) {
            R.id.btnLogout -> {
                logout()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, this is case to case basis.. Follow this steps, debug you button before clicking, if debug not works on logout button, use any other button and check for clickable properties in your logout btn. Inspect your layout, you may have some other view intercepting above button, that stopping the click event.

Comment: I'll explain besides this button I have another button with the same problem that is not present in the code now, both do not handle the click event, I tried your solution to record a few clicks on a view but the code does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Remove attribute `clickable` in your xml file, that's will override your click listener.

Comment: i have remove it but not change anything

Comment: I have checked your code, maybe your app main thread was blocked.